# How to transform individual record in flat file to one xml using apache camel instead of list of xml records

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel, bindy

***CamelConfig.java***

```
@Component
public class CamelConfig extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        try {
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            ConverterRoute route = new ConverterRoute();
            route.addRoutesToCamelContext(context);
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            context.stop();

        } catch (Exception exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***ConverterRoute.java***

```
public class ConverterRoute implements RoutesBuilder {

    private static final String SOURCE_INPUT_PATH = "file://inbox?fileName=Source.txt";

    private static final String SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH = "file://outbox?fileName=file.xml";

    public void addRoutesToCamelContext(CamelContext context) throws Exception {

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                try {
                    DataFormat bindyFixed = new BindyCsvDataFormat(Test.class);

                    from(SOURCE_INPUT_PATH).
                            unmarshal(bindyFixed).
                            marshal().
                            xstream().
                            to(SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH).log("Finished Transformation").end();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

***Source.txt***

```
55158|11901|2346
55158|11101|3454
```

***Test.java***

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\\|",skipField = true,name = "Test")
public class Test {

    @DataField(pos = 1,name = "ALT_NUM")
    private BigDecimal ALT_NUM;

    @DataField(pos = 2,name = "PRTNUM")
    private BigDecimal PRTNUM;

    @DataField(pos = 3,name = "UOMCOD")
    private Integer UOMCOD;

}
```

***OUTPUT***

*** File.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<list>
    <com.john.Test>
            <ALT_NUM>55158</ALT_NUM>
            <PRTNUM>11901</PRTNUM>
            <UOMCOD>2346</UOMCOD>
    </com.john.Test>
    <com.john.Test>
            <TRNNAM>55158</TRNNAM>
            <PRTNUM>11901</PRTNUM>
            <UOMCOD>3454</UOMCOD>
    </com.john.Test>
</list>
```

***Expected Output***

***fileOne.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>    
    <Test>
            <ALT_NUM>55158</ALT_NUM>
            <PRTNUM>11901</PRTNUM>
            <UOMCOD>2346</UOMCOD>
    </Test>
```

***fileTwo.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>    
    <Test>
            <ALT_NUM>55158</ALT_NUM>
            <PRTNUM>11901</PRTNUM>
            <UOMCOD>3454</UOMCOD>
    </Test>
```

I was able to generate xml file with all the fields in single file.I want single record in single xml file. Can anyone help me.Also the tag names in the output file root element it is generating the package name of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use `split()` to process each line from the csv record separately.

```
from(SOURCE_INPUT_PATH).
 .split().tokenize(System.lineSeparator())
   unmarshal(bindyFixed).
   marshal().
   xstream().
   to(SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH).log("Finished Transformation").end();
```

Comment: I can see that split changes working.But how can I give unique filenames for individual xml files. Thanks Arun

Comment: Try replacing the SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH as below. This will solve unique file name issues up to seconds, but if 2 files are created in the same second, then you might have to create something at the micro secondth level

`private static final String SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH = "file://outbox?fileName=file.xml_$simple{date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}";`

Comment: nope it didn't worked. Still it is generating single file. with single record data.

Comment: Hey! It worked when I replaced that time stamp with micro secondth. Can I know how can I change the tag name. It was generating along with the package name (ex: com.john.test, I need just test instead of printing the whole pojo package name.